# Java ServerSocket connecting to same socket multiple times

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

So, I'm not for sure what the problem is here, but I'm trying to create a simple server in Java, but whenever a client connects (I've been connecting via a localhost request from Google Chrome) the one single client connection will connect more than one time. (ie. every time I connect to my server via my browser the server prints "User connected successfully" 2-5 times.) I am not for sure how the main thread could possibly race back up to the top of the loop and connect to the same client more than once.

```
...
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9876);
while(true)
{
   Socket s = ss.accept();
   if(count >= queuesize || count >= numproducers)
   {
     System.out.println("Thread pool has reached it's limit. User access denied.");
     //....
     //error message sent to user here
     //....
   }
   else
   {
      System.out.println("User connected successfully");
      for(int x=0;x<numproducers;x++)
      {
         if(threads.get(position).isAvailable())
         {
             threads.get(x).start(s);
             position = (position+1) % numproducers;
             break;
         }
         position = (position+1) % numproducers;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does it happen if you make your own client, or use say Telnet?

Comment: Have you considered that maybe Chrome is connecting multiple times? (Check with lsof, if you're on Linux, to see the open connections.)

Comment: please share the client code also.

Comment: @MarkW I am just using a request from a web browser. It does seem to be an http issue of some sort. When using telnet, it only connects once, but when using any web browser it sends multiple GET requests (my server is using http requests). Is there anyway to prevent the server from accepting more than one GET from the same client?

Comment: @vanza I am just using a request from a web browser. It does seem to be an http issue of some sort. When using telnet, it only connects once, but when using any web browser it sends multiple GET requests (my server is using http requests). Is there anyway to prevent the server from accepting more than one GET from the same client?

Comment: @Sp4mm4ge: you could probably do that, but do you want to? Browsers need to make several GET requests for very valid reasons (e.g. retrieve the resources linked from an HTML page). Also, take a look at HTTP 1.1 keep alive connections.

Comment: Heh evidently I would make a crappy internet. I think you just might find the answer to why you get multiple GET's in this spec: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1  Section 8.1.2.1 tells you how to communicate with the remote client on what you intend to do with the connection.

Comment: @vanza Makes sense. My application gets a connection and then sends an image to the client depending on their input.  I guess it seems annoying that the server is receiving multiple requests but it isn't hurting anything so I could just deal with it.

Comment: @MarkW Thanks for the spec. (I would vote you guys up, but sadly I don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround. It might help you.

- Create a `Set` or `Map` containing hash code of all the connected `Socket` from server at below line

  ```
  Socket s = ss.accept();
  ```
- Now check every time whenever a new client is trying to connect, if its a same `Socket` then do nothing or close the socket.

Comment: I might just keep the multiple connections as I've realized it isn't harming anything, but if I decide not to then this seems like a great solution. Thanks! (I thought about something like this, but I didn't think about using a set)

Comment: It can't possibly be the same `Socket`. It is always a new socket. The answer doesn't make sense and the suggesitd solution is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how the main thread could possibly race back up to the top of the loop and connect to the same client more than once.

Well:

- you have an accept loop, which answers part of that, and
- there is nothing to stop the browser from forming more than one connection to you

so it happens.

Browsers frequently do this to load embedded resources, such as images, style sheets, JavaScript, etc.